# Resource file C#

Tags: c#, winforms, resources

I want to add like this resource file 
[image]

but when I add resource file to project, It seems like [image]

How can I add like first?

Comment: It seems to display differently because on the first picture, the file is shown on the `OutOfDepartement.cs` form level and on the second picture, i guess, on the project level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done by Visual Studio automatically when you add a new Form to your project. The underlying mechanism is simple but if you want to do it manually, you'll have to edit your `csproj` file in a text editor and add some xml artifacts to your newly added resource file node.

There is a xml property called `DependentUpon` that you can set in the `csproj` and Visual Studio will then show that node under the parent Form that you set.

Here is the relevant section for one such entry from the project file (I'm using VB project here, but CS should be similar):

```
<Compile Include="My Project\Resources.Designer.vb">
  <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
  <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
  <DependentUpon>Resources.resx</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

The `DependentUpon` line is what links `Resources.Designer.vb` and `Resources.resx` in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: There is a handy [VS extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.FileNesting) for this.

Answer (score 0):

I added like another file

```
<EmbeddedResource Include="OutOfDepartment.tr-TR.resx">
      <DependentUpon>OutOfDepartment.cs</DependentUpon>
    </EmbeddedResource>
```

but it seems this [image]

Comment: See if the order of entries in `csproj` makes any difference. Also make sure you add both files normally through VS and edit it manually after that.

Comment: Done! I added new resources file and write to name OutOfDepartment.tr-TR.resx and automatically added! Thank you so much!